# how to Parse String Date to MongoDB date type

Tags: java, mongodb, date

i'm have string dates like `Wed Aug 17 17:22:51 IST 2016` to parse to ISOdate. so I have tried following code to do that.

```
String tdate = "Wed Aug 17 17:22:51 IST 2016";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date pubDate = sdf.parse(tdate);
```

but it gave me:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Aug 17 17:22:51 IST 2016"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try parsing with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

hope it helped